# Can you give an example in a formal definition?

Tags: thesis, writing-style

I would like to give an example in a formal definition. My concern is, by giving an example, I am implicitly demonstrating that the definition is not precise/clear enough.

Is it acceptable to give an example in a formal definition?

Comment: Actually, formal definitions, say in mathematics, usually require some additional explanation.

Comment: And definitions in maths would be very different from those written in the [Natural Semantic Metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_semantic_metalanguage).

Comment: Note that the word "formal" has different meanings to different people. To Math persons, it refers to a precise mathematical definition. In less pure fields, definitions might be less precise, since natural language is inherently imprecise. But examples should generally only be used to illustrate definitions, not to specify them (as pointed out in vonbrand's answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the definition itself, no. It just should be that: A definition. You should add examples and/or motivations in the surrounding text, so your reader (a befuddled human being, not an automaton!) sees what is going on, and where you want to go.

Answer (score 5):

In mathematics, the definition of a concept is an essential ingredient of all proofs involving that concept. The definition must therefore be sufficiently clear and precise to serve that purpose in rigorous proofs.

The goal of precision may conflict with other worthwhile goals, for example ease of understanding, motivation, and hints about the role of the defined concept in a broader theory.  Nevertheless, I'd insist on precision in the definition itself, and use examples (and other sorts of information) outside the definition, if necessary, to serve those other goals.